# Определение четности/нечетности количества символов в строке (R)

Tags: r

Дано задание: *Напишите функцию is.odd(), которая возвращает значение TRUE, если число символов в строке нечетно, FALSE, если число символов в строке четно.*

В программе курса ещё не была раскрыта тема условий в R, поэтому решение должно быть без if и else, как я понимаю. В этом и заключается проблема Понимаю, что нужно считать количество символов в строке и делить нацело (как сделала бы в питоне), но что-то, очевидно, упускаю из вида.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать оператор модуля `%%`

```r
is.odd <- function(n)
  as.logical(nchar(n) %% 2)

is.odd('sasd1kty4s')
[1] FALSE

is.odd('yS8rd')
[1] TRUE
```